# JS: Remove everything after nth interation of chacter

Tags: javascript

Trying to convert RGBA to HEX, discarding the transparency. There are a number of ways to convert RGB to HEX, and it seems the simplest way to get HEX out of RGBA is to simply discard the content of the alpha.

Hoping to turn this:

`rgba(255,255,255,0.95)`

Into this:

`rgb(255,255,255)`

Then use this:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/29/convert-rgb-to-hex.aspx

to get `#FFFFFF`

Open to a direct conversion as well, this just seems like a simple substring operation which eludes me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
input.replace(/rgba\((\d+,\d+,\d+),[\d.]+\)/,"rgb($1)")
```

Exlanation for the regex:

- `/` - start of regex
- `rgba\(` - literal `rgba(`
- `(` - start of capturing group
- `\d+,\d+,\d+` - three groups of digits, separated by commas
- `)` - end of capturing group
- `,[\d.]+\)` - one more comma, group of digits and decimal points and a closing parenthesis
- `/` - end of regex

Replace with: literal `rgb(`, the captured string, literal `)`

To make this regex more universally applicable, allow whitespace where the spec allows it:

```
input.replace(/rgba\((\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*),\s*[\d.]+\s*\)/,"rgb($1)")
```

Comment: I just tried that both dynamically and with `"rgba(255,255,255,0.95)"` and it didn't work. I see where you're going, but I think there's a typo in there somewhere.

Comment: Got it, works like a charm. Thanks Jan! You answer a lot of my late night questions :)